# How to revert back to windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I'm gonna try to run Linux on my pc. I was going to originally dual boot but found that it would cause too much trouble and I really would rather not mess with partitions. So, if I decide to erase everything and move to linux. How can I go back? would the recovery menu do anything? Do I need to make a second bootable usb of windows? This is really for peace of mind that I can go back if it turns out that I have problems with it. Please help because I would like to be prepared when I decide to switch from win10 to ubuntu.

Comment: Isn't this question essentially [the same one you asked a few hours ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310692/i-want-to-switch-to-ubuntu-from-windows-but-have-some-questions-please-answer)? If you are concerned, run Linux in a VM until you gain confidence in the system. When you're ready, then you can consider a dual-boot. Over time, you may even lean towards a preference and have a single OS with others operating only in VMs. The wonderful thing about VMs is that the cost of error is essentially nil.

Comment: @Matigo its similar but that one covers dual booting, this is just how I would go over getting back without dual booting. I was told to just dual boot in that post. In this one I'm trying to get information on how to go back without having set up a dual boot and instead completely overwriting windows with linux. Also VMs never run at a usable framerate for me.

Comment: If the goal is to run games in a VM, then you'll certainly have a problem. If the goal is to use Ubuntu to accomplish a task, then chances are a VM will work just fine. Ambiguity in intention does not serve any purpose here.

Comment: @Matigo I'm sorry, I shouldn't have used the word framerate. What I mean is that the animations are tearing, buttons take multiple seconds to respond, etc. I'm very new to all this so I'm sorry if there is any confusion.

Comment: You have an Intel i7-7700HQ 2.80Ghz, a Geforce GTX 1050, and 12GB of RAM. If there is lag that is measured in *multiple full seconds*, that's usually a problem with the VM engine, not the VM client. Grab a copy of VirtualBox, use the `VBoxVGA` graphics controller, boost the video memory up to max and enable the 3D acceleration. Once the OS is installed, install the "VirtualBox Additional AddOns" software, which includes a proper video driver, and you'll be golden. I've been doing this for years and can watch YouTube videos in the VM if I choose (mind you, it's an Ubuntu host that I use)

Comment: @Matigo Thanks for the response, I will see if I can get it to work. Its probably also because I installed it on a HDD and not a SSD. I also had problems installing the addons but I'm sure I can find a guide out there. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: You should reference Windows support to learn how to install Windows. The existing operating system is irrelevant since you will be replacing it.

Comment: @Matigo would installing the VM on a SSD make it faster?